# Unable to set browser cookies inside Selenium with Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

If I launch Chrome with Python Selenium like:

```
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=%s" % USER_AGENT)
opts.add_argument("--start-maximized")
opts.add_argument('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')
opts.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
opts.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
opts.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"credentials_enable_service": False, "profile.password_manager_enabled": False})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=opts)
```

launch a window, neither Selenium, nor myself manually in the browser, can set cookies.

If I try:

```
driver.get('http://www.example.com')
```

I have some Javascript that retrieves the cookie value for `mycookie`, which reports the value:

```
abc
```

but then if I do:

```
driver.add_cookie({"name": "mycookie", "domain": "example.com", "value": "123"})
```

and then try to access it from Javascript, it reports the old `abc` value.

And if I manually use the console to try:

```
Cookies.set("mycookie", "123", {expires: 1});
Cookies.get("mycookie");
```

it still reports the old `abc` value.

Why am I unable to set cookie values with this Selenium configuration?

Comment: I would leave out the domain (it'll default to current domain)... you can only set it to the current browsing context's domain anyway, so setting it is redundant and could possibly cause an issue.  Try/catching to see exception when setting the cookie should help you troubleshoot.  (The console "Cookies.set" command doesn't seem correct... are you sure the syntax is right? )

Comment: Seems like console test would be: document.cookie="mycookie=123";  Then check with document.cookie;

Comment: @pcalkins I'm using [the js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) package to simply cookie access. It's working perfectly outside of Selenium.

Comment: gotcha.... I would check the cookie you are trying to change to see if it's set to HTTP-Only.  If so you can only modify it using the incoming request headers.  You might try the new "bidi" interface for that: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/bidi_api/#network-interception

Comment: Leaving out the domain, at least when using localhost, fixed my issue. Thanks @pcalkins!